# SAS Do loop over Set statement

Tags: sas

I have a dataset named as test, with one numeric variable named 'id' having 3 observations as:

```
1
2
3
```

I am creating another one using do loop as below:

```
DATA abc;
 DO i = 1 to 3;
   SET test;
    m+1;
    OUTPUT;
 END;
RUN;
```

This returns 3 observations.

If I change do loop from 1 to 4 and **remove the output statement**, I get an empty dataset. I am unable to get my head around this. Can someone please explain this?

Comment: That does not seem true. What did the LOG say?  Your data step should have written 3 observations if the input data `test` had 3 observations even if you set the upper bound on the DO loop to 2,000.

Comment: @Tom statement is correct, you have some other issue. What is the variable name in your 'test' data set?

Comment: I just corrected my question. I get an empty datset if I remove the output statement from do loop. The variable name is 'id' in the test dataset when looping 1 to 4.              What I am unable to understand is that SET statement reads entire dataset, so by DO loop 3 times, should we not read the entire data 3 times, to get 9 observations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most SAS data steps actually end when the step executes a SET or INPUT statement and finds there is no more input available. That is what is happening.

SAS normally writes the observations at the end of the data step iteration. The exception is when you have an explicit OUTPUT statement coded.  So without the OUTPUT step  SAS will only write out an observation when it gets to the end of the data step.  So when you rmeoved the OUTPUT you made the step the same as:

```
DATA abc;
 DO i = 1 to 3;
   SET test;
    m+1;
 END;
 OUTPUT;
RUN;
```

But if your DO loop iterates more times than there are observations for the SET statement to read then it will never get to the end to write the output since it will read past the end of the input dataset and stop.

Comment: Thank you so much.. Is it possible that you can please create a chat room with me, I just want to quickly understand something.. Another suitable timing would be ok too.